# Got small output value error between .h5 model and .pb model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I tried both on `tf-gpu1.4+keras2.1.3` and on `tf-gpu1.12+keras2.2.4` and the problem always happens.

The problem is:  **After I converted the keras.application.ResNet50() model into freeze graph model in .pb format, I feed in the same picture into the converted .pb model but the output value changes just a little.**

Below is the codes, which prints the first 10 element of the ResNet output vector , and also freeze the graph to output pb model file:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util_impl import convert_variables_to_constants
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, ResNet50
import keras.backend as K
K.set_learning_phase(0)

img = image.load_img('images/34rews.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x_input = preprocess_input(x)

net_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling='avg')
sess = K.get_session()
preds = sess.run(net_model.get_output_at(0), feed_dict={net_model.get_input_at(0): x_input})
print('before convert to pb :', np.array(preds).squeeze()[:10])

output_name0 = net_model.get_output_at(0).op.name  # 'global_average_pooling2d_1/Mean'
constant_graph = convert_variables_to_constants(sess, sess.graph_def, [output_name0])

with tf.gfile.GFile('saved_model_constant.pb', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(constant_graph.SerializeToString())
```

and the print log is :

```
before convert to pb : [**0.99536467** 0.31807986 2.0998483  0.9077819  0.10606026 0.93215793
 0.04187933 0.10000334 1.1727284  1.0535308 ]
```

Then we predict the same image through the pb file generated by above codes:

```
def test_constant(pb_dir, img_path='images/34rews.jpg'):
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)

    from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        with gfile.FastGFile(pb_dir, 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

        result = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, return_elements=["global_average_pooling2d_1/Mean:0"], name='')
        preds = sess.run(result, feed_dict={sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_1:0'):x})
        print('using pb file:', np.array(preds).squeeze()[:10])
```

The output printing log is:

```
using pb file: [**0.99536514** 0.3180797  2.0998483  0.90778273 0.10606024 0.9321572
 0.04187941 0.10000295 1.1727289  1.0535315 ]
```

I can clearly find the extreme small value error of the predict vector, between the original keras model and the pb model after using the freeze graph method.
e.g. The first element value of the resnet output vector using original keras model is **0.99536467**, but the output one is **0.99536514** using the converted pb file. 
I wonder why there is such a small value error? It may not cause big accuracy error but it is really strange!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `K.set_learning_phase(0)` and the problem is solved. Maybe it could be better to let Keras to handle with the K.learning_phase() by iteself.
For my experiment, use the value of Keras.model.predict() as the correct outcome:

```
with K.set_learning_phase(0) and without convert_variables_to_constants:  value is the same.
without K.set_learning_phase(0) and without convert_variables_to_constants:  value is the same.
without K.set_learning_phase(0) and with convert_variables_to_constants:  value is the same.
with K.set_learning_phase(0) and with convert_variables_to_constants:  value is changed!
```